# How to saving data concatened sent via form?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

Now I have problems to understand my implementation

My Servlet

```
package br.com.cad.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import br.com.cad.dao.Cadastro;
import br.com.cad.basica.Contato;

public class AddDados extends HttpServlet{

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   
            throws IOException, ServletException { 


 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

 ...

    StringBuilder finalDate = new StringBuilder("DataNascimento1")
.append("/"+request.getParameter("DataNascimento‌​2"))
.append("/"+request.getParameter("DataNascimento3"));

 try {  
     Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //here there are error 
     finalDate.toString(); 

 } catch(ParseException e) {  
     out.println("Erro de conversão da data");  
     return;   
 } 
 Contato contato = new Contato();  
     ??????????
```

My Object Dao

```
    package br.com.cad.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Date;

import br.com.cad.dao.ConnectDb;
import br.com.cad.basica.Contato;
public class Cadastro {  

    private Connection connection;  


    public Cadastro() {  
        this.connection = new ConnectDb().getConnection();  
    }  

    public void adiciona(Contato contato) {  
        String sql = "INSERT INTO dados_cadastro(pf_nome, pf_ultimonome, pf_rg, pf_cpf, pf_sexo,pf_dt_nasc) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";  
        try {  

            PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setDate(6, new Date( contato.getDataNascimento1().getTimeInMillis()) );
stmt.execute();  
            stmt.close();  
            System.out.println("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!.");  
        } catch(SQLException sqlException) {  
            throw new RuntimeException(sqlException);  
        }  
    }
```

My Class Contato

```
package br.com.cad.basica;
```

import java.util.Calendar;

public class Contato {

```
    private Long id;
    private String nome;
    private String sobrenome;
    private String email;
    private String endereco;
    private Calendar dataNascimento1;
    private Calendar dataNascimento2;
    private Calendar dataNascimento3;
    private String rg;
    private String cpf;
    private String sexo;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getSobrenome() {
        return sobrenome;
    }


... getters and setters...
```

Please help me to identify some errors in my code and implement it to saving data in my db...

Answer (score 0):

You should pass value as 01, 02, 03 but not 1, 2, 3 (for days and months). Check your web form and date selection values.

Comment: I have error: 
message Servlet execution threw an exception
description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
root cause
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
dataNascimento1 cannot be resolved to a variable
dataNascimento2 cannot be resolved to a variable
dataNascimento3 cannot be resolved to a variable
br.com.cad.servlet.AddDados.service(AddDados.java:52)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //here there are error
```

This is wrong declaration .

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

This will not cause problem.

Comment: OK now my class is: ... StringBuilder finalDate = new StringBuilder("DataNascimento1")
.append("/"+request.getParameter("DataNascimento‌​2"))
.append("/"+request.getParameter("DataNascimento3"));
  
 try {  
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
     finalDate.toString(); 
      
 } catch(ParseException e) {  
     out.println("Erro de conversão da data");  
     return;   
 }  Contato contato = new Contato(); contato.setDataNascimento1(dataNascimento1);
  contato.setDataNascimento2(dataNascimento2);
  contato.setDataNascimento3(dataNascimento3); error here ...

Comment: Please avoid pasting code in comment..please edit question with your code.